# Tricky MySQL query involving NOT IN

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables that I am joining together in order to get results.
One table contains a list of assessments with a unique ID (assessments), whilst the other table (staff_to_assessments) contains a list of assessments that are assigned to staff members. An example record for this table would contain the Staff member unique ID, and the assignment unique ID. This shows that a user has been linked to an assignment.

I have written a function which only grabs assessments from the assessment table where they have not been assigned to a staff member in staff_to_assessment table. This is to populate a drop-down box on the front end where these remaining assessments can be assigned to a staff member if required, therefore I don;t want to show any that are already assigned.

MySQL query is as follows:

```
    SELECT * FROM assessments a 
    LEFT JOIN staff_to_assessment s2a ON a.assessment_id = s2a.assessment_id                            
    WHERE a.assessment_id NOT IN
         (SELECT assessment_id FROM staff_to_assessment WHERE staff_id = '" . (int)$options['staffId'] . "')";
```

This doesn't seem to generate the response I need. Can anybody see where I have gone wrong?
Thanks!!

Comment: I think `WHERE NOT EXISTS (subquery)` will do the stuff

Comment: NOT IN also works no need for NOT EXISTS

Comment: If the `staff_id` column is a numeric value, no need for the `'`s around it... `...WHERE staff_id = " . (int)$options['staffId'] . ")";` Also, where does the $options array come from? Is it coming from the user, e.g. HTTP parameters? It might pose a security threat... Consider using parametrised SQL queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your query is working too hard.  You just need to find rows where there is no match to the `left outer join`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM assessments a LEFT JOIN
     staff_to_assessment s2a
     ON a.assessment_id = s2a.assessment_id                            
WHERE s2a.assessment_id is null;
```

You don't need to use both a `left join` and a `not in` clause.

Comment: Thanks. The strange thing is is that I am getting the correct record back albeit with no data! Like here:   [0] => Array
        (
            [assessment_id] => 
            [name] => Test Assessment
            [description] => TEST ASSESSMENT 3
            [active] => 0
            [staff_to_assessment_id] => 
            [staff_id] => 
        )

Comment: @funkyjimbob . . . I think the issue is a naming conflict when using `*` and having the same column names in different tables.  You only need values from `a` anyway, so I added the alias in.

Answer (score 0):

Queries like `NOT IN [subquery]` can (and should) always be rewritten as a `LEFT JOIN`.

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM assessments a 
LEFT JOIN staff_to_assessment s2a USING (assessment_id) -- equivalent to "ON a.assessment_id = s2a.assessment_id", as both columns have the same name
WHERE staff_id IS NULL
```

This is equivalent to:

```sql
SELECT a.*
FROM assessments a 
WHERE a.assessment_id NOT IN (SELECT assessment_id FROM staff_to_assessment)
```

Both are usually optimised away to the same execution plan, but the former is preferable as it tends to produce quicker queries.